# Group into current row previous group values with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I have a pyspark dataframe organised in this way:

| ID | timestamp | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | x |
| 2 | 1 | a | y |
| 1 | 2 | b | x |
| 2 | 2 | b | y |
| 1 | 3 | c | y |
| 2 | 3 | d | y |
| 1 | 4 | l | y |
| 2 | 4 | s | y |

and let's say that the timestamp is the number of day from the beginning of time. What I'd like to do is, for each line, to group into a list the values up to -x days regarding the current ID, so to have:

| ID | timestamp | value1 | value2 | list_value_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | X | a |
| 2 | 1 | a | y | a |
| 1 | 2 | b | x | a,b |
| 2 | 2 | b | y | a,b |
| 1 | 3 | c | y | a,b,c |
| 2 | 3 | d | y | a,b,d |
| 1 | 3 | c | y | b,c,l |
| 2 | 3 | d | y | b,d,s |

I imagine I should do that with a Window but I'm not sure on how to proceed (I'm quite bad with Windows for some reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a `collect_list` over a Window betweeen the current row and two preceding rows, and combine the list into a comma-separated string using `concat_ws`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'list_value_1', 
    F.concat_ws(',', 
        F.collect_list('value1').over(
            Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('timestamp').rowsBetween(-2, 0)
        )
    )
)

df2.show()
+---+---------+------+------+------------+
| ID|timestamp|value1|value2|list_value_1|
+---+---------+------+------+------------+
|  1|        1|     a|     x|           a|
|  1|        2|     b|     x|         a,b|
|  1|        3|     c|     y|       a,b,c|
|  1|        4|     l|     y|       b,c,l|
|  2|        1|     a|     y|           a|
|  2|        2|     b|     y|         a,b|
|  2|        3|     d|     y|       a,b,d|
|  2|        4|     s|     y|       b,d,s|
+---+---------+------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the comma transformation is not needed since I only need them in a list. I had to delete the usual convention of using [el1,el2,...] because for some reason stack overflow was having problems with it in a table

Comment: then you can remove the concat_ws part of the code

Comment: Yep, done that, I only wanted to add it for other eventual readers :)

Comment: After a long time @mck I discovered this is wrong, in fact this solution works only if you have the number of rows that is equal to the number of timestamps, if this is not the case and for example we have two datapoint with the same timestamp the list will be wrong.